# Unable to use HTTP2 in HttpClient .Net

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient, http2

I'm trying to request data over HTTP 2.0. I'm using the HttpClient from .Net 5. I'm on Windows 10. The problem is that the version on the response seems to always be "1.1". What am I doing wrong here?

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string authToken =  "{jwt token}";
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);

        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "{url}")
        {
            Version = new Version(2, 0)
        };

        var x = httpClient.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var version = x.Version;
        Console.WriteLine(version);
```

Comment: Does [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/#http-2) help?